# Apt-Get Upgrade Modified Sudoers File

Tags: apt, upgrade, sudo

Ubuntu 16.04LTS -

I just ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y`

After it was finished I tried to run another command with `sudo`  and was greeted by the following error:

```
username is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I tried another account with sudo permissions and got the same message. What in the world just happened?

I was able to see the following packages got updated:

```
will@will-laptop:/mnt/c/Users/wdavis$ cat updates.txt
Setting up perl-base (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.3) ...
Setting up libpam0g:amd64 (1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up libpam-modules-bin (1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up libpam-modules:amd64 (1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up libpam-runtime (1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up perl-modules-5.22 (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.3) ...
Setting up libperl5.22:amd64 (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.3) ...
Setting up perl (5.22.1-9ubuntu0.3) ...
Setting up grub-common (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.18) ...
Setting up grub2-common (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.18) ...
Setting up grub-pc-bin (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.18) ...
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.18) ...
Setting up libprocps4:amd64 (2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2.4) ...
Setting up procps (2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2.4) ...
Setting up distro-info-data (0.28ubuntu0.8) ...
Setting up ifupdown (0.8.10ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up libssl1.0.0:amd64 (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.12) ...
Setting up linux-base (4.5ubuntu1~16.04.1) ...
Setting up hdparm (9.48+ds-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3.3) ...
Setting up libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.8) ...
Setting up curl (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.8) ...
Setting up ldap-utils (2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3.3) ...
Setting up libelf1:amd64 (0.165-3ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libdw1:amd64 (0.165-3ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libplymouth4:amd64 (0.9.2-3ubuntu13.5) ...
Setting up openssl (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.12) ...
Setting up plymouth (0.9.2-3ubuntu13.5) ...
Setting up plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (0.9.2-3ubuntu13.5) ...
Setting up wget (1.17.1-1ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up xdg-user-dirs (0.15-2ubuntu6.16.04.1) ...
Setting up python3-problem-report (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.18) ...
Setting up python3-apport (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.18) ...
Setting up apport (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.18) ...
Setting up docker-ce (18.03.1~ce-0~ubuntu) ...
Setting up git-man (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up git (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up linux-cloud-tools-common (4.4.0-127.153) ...
Setting up linux-cloud-tools-virtual-lts-xenial (4.4.0.127.133) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (1.157.19) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.4.0-127.153) ...
Setting up linux-tools-common (4.4.0-127.153) ...
Setting up linux-tools-virtual-lts-xenial (4.4.0.127.133) ...
Setting up linux-virtual-lts-xenial (4.4.0.127.133) ...
Setting up patch (2.7.5-1ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up snapd (2.32.9) ...
Setting up cloud-guest-utils (0.27-0ubuntu25.1) ...
Setting up datadog-agent (1:6.2.1-1) ...
Setting up grub-legacy-ec2 (18.2-4-g05926e48-0ubuntu1~16.04.2) ...
Setting up python-sss (1.13.4-1ubuntu1.11) ...
Setting up libsss-idmap0 (1.13.4-1ubuntu1.11) ...
Setting up libsss-nss-idmap0 (1.13.4-1ubuntu1.11) ...
Setting up sssd-common (1.13.4-1ubuntu1.11) ...
Setting up sssd-tools (1.13.4-1ubuntu1.11) ...
Setting up sssd-proxy (1.13.4-1ubuntu1.11) ...
Setting up sssd-krb5-common (1.13.4-1ubuntu1.11) ...
Setting up sssd-ldap (1.13.4-1ubuntu1.11) ...
Setting up sssd-krb5 (1.13.4-1ubuntu1.11) ...
Setting up libipa-hbac0 (1.13.4-1ubuntu1.11) ...
Setting up sssd-ad-common (1.13.4-1ubuntu1.11) ...
Setting up sssd-ipa (1.13.4-1ubuntu1.11) ...
Setting up sssd-ad (1.13.4-1ubuntu1.11) ...
Setting up sssd (1.13.4-1ubuntu1.11) ...
Setting up libnss-sss:amd64 (1.13.4-1ubuntu1.11) ...
Setting up libpam-sss:amd64 (1.13.4-1ubuntu1.11) ...
Setting up libsss-sudo (1.13.4-1ubuntu1.11) ...
Setting up vlan (1.9-3.2ubuntu1.16.04.5) ...
Setting up python3-distupgrade (1:16.04.25) ...
Setting up python3-update-manager (1:16.04.13) ...
Setting up ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:16.04.25) ...
Setting up update-manager-core (1:16.04.13) ...
```

**OUTPUT OF GROUPS**

```
willd@syn.local@DockerSwarm02:~$ groups
domain users@syn.local domain admins@syn.local enterprise admins@syn.local denied rodc password replication group@syn.local sql admins@syn.local synadmin@syn.local syndevel@syn.local synitops@syn.local syn admins@syn.local syndevelopers@syn.local syndb-read-prod@syn.local syndb-read-qa@syn.local syndb-write-backups@syn.local syndb-write-prod@syn.local syndb-write-qa@syn.local synlma-itops@syn.local synlma-prod@syn.local synlma-qa@syn.local synlma-synutilserver@syn.local synrdp-fin@syn.local synrdp-prod@syn.local synrdp-qa@syn.local synrdp-utility@syn.local vpn users@syn.local strictpasswordpolicygroup@syn.local syntechnology@syn.local

syn@DockerSwarm02:~$ groups
syn adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lxd lpadmin sambashare
```

**OUTPUT OF nsswitch.conf**

```
syn@DockerSwarm02:~$ cat cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
cat: cat: No such file or directory
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat sss
group:          compat sss
shadow:         compat sss
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files sss
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis sss
sudoers:        file sss
```

**UPDATE SUDOERS:**

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
%Domain\ Admins@syn.local ALL=(ALL) ALL
%domain\ admins@syn.local ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

**UPDATE PKEXEC:**

```
syn@DockerSwarm02:~$ pkexec cat /etc/sudoers
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is needed to run `/bin/cat' as the super user
Authenticating as: syn,,, (syn)
Password:
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
```

**UPDATE PAM.D/SUDO**

```
root@DockerSwarm02:/etc/pam.d# cat sudo
#%PAM-1.0

session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

**UPDATE SSS**

After removing sss from nsswitch.conf things are working again. Seems this update of SSS broke something.

Comment: The user I was logged in as when I ran the update is an AD user. However the 2nd account I tried was a local account, and is the account we used when we setup the system originally (so we know for a fact it had sudo privs)

Comment: Add the output of `groups` run as both users, and `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf` to the question please. Do you have any other ways of getting root? `su`? `pkexec`?

Comment: I just recreated this on another machine, but I set a password on root first. It seems that if I ran the update logged in as an AD user this happens. I'll work on getting those

Comment: @muru - Question updated.

Comment: If I read that right, the AD user is not part of the sudo group but the local user is. The sudo group is usually how local users are granted sudo rights, so I assume some modification was done to sudoers before this? How was that done? If you do have root access, can you post your sudoers as well?

Comment: @muru added sudoers - we did modify it to add the domain admins group.

Comment: So: group membership - check. NSS includes both standard sources and AD - check. sudoers includes both `%sudo` and the AD group - check. (And more importantly, it seems `sudoers` *hasn't* been modified by the upgrade.) I think that leaves PAM (`/etc/pam.d/sudo`) as one more possible problem point. Also, does `pkexec` continue to work?

Comment: @muru - Added output of pkexec and pam.d/sudo